# 4 way dimmer with 3 other switches

Tags: electrical

I have a set of canned lights that are switched from 4 different locations and each of those switches have 4 wires to them. How can I use a Dimmer Switch? I have installed Numerous 3 way dimmers in the house already, Lutron Maestro. Any way to use these? Or can you recommend what to use?

Comment: Do you want dimming control at all the locations?  Also, can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved?

Comment: Are you sure each of the four switches have 4 wires, not counting grounds?  I'm thinking there should be 2 3-way switches and 2 4-way switches.  What type of bulbs are you using?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: you will need a smart dimming solution if you want to be able to adjust the light level from more than one switch.